# Getting per-user or per-command CPU/load information for Linux

Tags: linux, cpu, statistics

I have a stock-standard LAMP stack running on a Centos 7 (Linux 3.10.0) machine.  The Apache web server passes requests to run PHP files to a number of php-fpm processes, which run under different user accounts mapped to various virtual web servers.  All of the php-fpm processes/programs access different databases handled by the one MariaDB instance.

The system is starting to experience some load and I'd like to know why and where. :)

Doing a 'top' it's my impression that that bottleneck is the mysqld MariaDB process/threads, but I'd like to delve deeper.  I'm not too familiar with process accounting under Linux so thought I'd seek advice here.

I've installed the 'psacct' RPM which gives me 'lastcomm'.  lastcomm is fine for giving me the CPU time expended by terminated processes, but I can't really use it on my running system, as the mysqld process never terminates.  So I can't use lastcomm to get an idea of where ALL of the CPU time is going and work out what is the CPU hog.

'sar' is fine, but it only gives me - as far as I know - global machine statistics.  No way to ask it to divide those into per-user or per-command figures.  If there is I'd appreciate being told how.

Is there a way I can get statistics on the CPU used - to-date or within a period of time - for all processes, terminated or otherwise, divided by user/command?

Also, is there any way I can get other metrics than just CPU - disk I/O or 'load' (runnable but blocked on CPU or disk I/O) - broken up by user/command?

Many thanks for any advice or references to 'Linux accounting for dummies'.

Answer (score 0):

These will help you:

Cacti is graphical and good:
http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/fedora-rhel-install-cacti-monitoring-rrd-software/

iotop: command line for IO ops

htop: much better and nicer top

Comment: Thanks for those.  Cacti is cute and looks good for overall system monitoring and presentation - reminds me of collectd - but it doesn't look to me that it has any data sources to gather the figures I want.